# How to calculate End and start Week?

Tags: sql, sql-server

how does one calculate the beginning of a week from a given date e.g 23 March 2010 beginning of the week is 21 March 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the value of DATEFIRST (I'm assuming 7 here, i.e. Sunday):

```
SELECT columnname - (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, columnname) - 1) AS week_start
FROM Table1
```

Then week_end is of course 7 days later.